# Why is it overwriting the user's previous data entered in my csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

This is my code:

```
class CSV:
    def __init__(self, path, hdrs):
    self.path = path  # raw string path; i.e. using r"/path/to/file"
    self.headers = hdrs  # list of strings ['Username', 'Password']
    self.created = False

    def create(self):
        with open(self.path, 'w', newline='') as f:
            w = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
            w.writerow(self.headers)
        self.created = True
        return self.headers

    def read(self):
        with open(self.path, 'r', newline='') as f:
            r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
            rows = list(r)
        return rows

    def write(self, data):  # list of strings ['Username', 'Password']
        if not self.created:
            rows = [self.create()]  # create list of lists
        else:
            rows = self.read()  # this is a list of lists by default
        rows.append(data)
        with open(self.path, 'w', newline='') as f:
            w = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
            w.writerows(rows)

def register():
    print ("Your username will now be created from your first name and age.")
    fname = input("Please enter your first name: ")
    age = input("Please enter your age: ")
    fname2 = fname[:3]
    username = fname2 + age
    print ("Your username is {}".format(username.upper()))
    password = input("Please enter a password for your new account: ")

    time.sleep(1.0)

    print ("Username: {}".format(username))
    print ("Password: {}".format(password))



    myCSV = CSV('/Users/Sidd/Desktop/python/Coursework/UserPass.csv', ['Username', 'Password'])
    new = [username, password]
    myCSV.write(new)
```

In the first block of code, it creates the Username and Password header in my csv file.

In the second block of code, it writes the user's username and password into the csv file Below the headers. But when another user enters another username and password, it overwrites the previous username and password, rather than going below the previous username and password in the csv file

How can I fix this?
Thank you.

Comment: Also, in my writer.writerow(...), how could I write it so that username is written below the header Username and password is written below the header Password

Comment: Any chance that you are always running both blocks by accident?

Comment: they're both separate. The first block first runs and creates the headers then closes the file. The seconds block reopens the file to append data.

Comment: So it works after the first time, but on the second time it overwrites the first?

Comment: yes. The first time when I enter the data, it appears in the csv file. But when I enter the data the second time, it overwrites the first data.

Comment: Well then, this is easy. When you call the first `with` again, you are opening it with `'w'` which truncates the file and thus deletes everything there.

Comment: So how do I avoid this.

Comment: You should only use the first block if you're creating the file for the first time, not when you're adding new data to an existing file.

Comment: but I don't want to append data in "w" mode, and if I do then it will overwrite anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It is overwriting it since you are calling the first `with` each time a new user comes along.

I'm not a big fan of the `'a'` method on file I/O. I've seen too many read/write corruptions. So instead, why not just:

- Create the document only once (so ignore calling the `DictWriter` again and again)
- Read the content and store it
- Append new content and overwrite

Give this a go, tested on my Python 3.6.2 as written! (minus `'/path/to/file'`)

```
import csv

class CSV:
    def __init__(self, path, hdrs):
        self.path = path # raw string path; i.e. using r"/path/to/file"
        self.headers = hdrs # list of strings ['Username', 'Password']
        self.created = False

    def create(self):
        with open(self.path, 'w', newline = '') as f:
            w = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ',')
            w.writerow(self.headers)
        self.created = True
        return self.headers

    def read(self):
        with open(self.path, 'r', newline = '') as f:
            r = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')
            rows = list(r)
        return rows

    def write(self, data): # list of strings ['Username', 'Password']
        if not self.created:
            rows = [self.create()] # create list of lists
        else:
            rows = self.read() # this is a list of lists by default
        rows.append(data)
        with open(self.path, 'w', newline = '') as f:
            w = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ',')
            w.writerows(rows)

def register(fin):
    print ("Your username will now be created from your first name and age.")
    name = input("Please enter your first name: ")
    age = input("Please enter your age: ")
    name2 = name[:3].upper()
    username = name2 + age
    print ("Your username is", username)
    password = input("Please enter a password for your new account: ")

    time.sleep(1.0)

    print ("Username:", username)
    print ("Password:", password)

    fin.write([username, password])

myCSV = CSV('/path/to/file', ['Username', 'Password'])
register(myCSV) # fill in with some values
register(myCSV) # fill in with some newer values
```

Comment: @SiddharthChaudhary Then you are not showing us your full implementation. As written, this code does not overwrite whatever was already in the CSV.

Comment: ah sorry, before what I'd shown, the user registers for a new account where the user enters a new username and password. This username and password is then taken and stored in the csv file. But my problem was, that when another user creates a new account, their username and password overwrites the first user's username and password

Comment: @SiddharthChaudhary This code that I have supplied to you does not overwrite it when a new username and password combo is supplied. For example, the `new` list in my example would be User#1; the `new2` would be User#2. Both users end up inside the CSV correctly. It is something on your end.

Comment: @SiddharthChaudhary I suggest you show your entire code (updated with mine if you chose to use it) in your original post so we can see what is going on.

Comment: @SiddharthChaudhary I already see a problem. Why is the `class` inside your `def register()`?

Comment: myCSV = CSV('/Users/Sidd/Desktop/python/Coursework/UserPass.csv', ['Username', 'Password'])
    new = [username, password]
    myCSV.write(new)

Comment: I've put the class outside the def register but now it doesn't write anything to the file. Look in my updated code

Comment: @SiddharthChaudhary Well did you ever try to call `register()`?

Comment: @SiddharthChaudhary I've made the edit including your new code. In your current code, every time you call `register()` you are overwriting the `myCSV` object; so thus never appending to the same object. You only ever need to create 1 CSV.